# How to create Google Forms using a Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have created a google spreadsheet to use as questions in my google form, it's the first time i'm using the apps script, and with the help of some videos I made a code, but the values of the spreadsheet are not going to the form, so the questions remain without a title and I have no idea how to fix it.

```
function myForm() {
var app=SpreadsheetApp;
var spreadsheet=app.openById("1iYXYufNQ1NMUibEFfSWVvfD0vVi14cqMQNBbIok_JzM");
var sheet=spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Atividades");
var form=FormApp;
var formFinal=form.openById("1_XYQcnlpg3EssBHI7X5T2QKyhplRj3FKufyBxPrJxQs");

formFinal
  .setTitle("Pesquisa de Tempo Estimado - Finalístico - Rodada 3")
  .setDescription("Área temática: Finalístico \nRodada: 3")
  .setConfirmationMessage("Obrigado pela participação!");

var item=formFinal.addSectionHeaderItem();
item.setTitle("Atividades");


sheet.getRange("A3:A14").getValues().map(function(elem,ind,obj){
  var item2=formFinal.addTextItem();
  item2.setTitle(elem[0]);
});

formFinal.setProgressBar(true);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add the data from A3:A14 and details about the code execution: what steps do you follow to execute the code and the error messages shown in the log / execution page.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run your script ( of course, I've changed the file ids ), and it seems to work fine.
One thing you shouldn't forget is **reloading** the form page after running the script.

Additional information: I've added the below code to clear all of the items of the form so that I can run the script repeatedly.

```js
  // clear all items
  var items = formFinal.getItems();
  while(items.length > 0){
    formFinal.deleteItem(items.pop());
  }
```